# Word 2016 show details button not working

Tags: lookup-column, word

I have Sharepoint 2013.  In one of my document libraries I have a lookup column that references a list on the same Sharepoint site.

We have just recently upgraded from Office 2010 to Office 2016.

When users create a new document in the document library in Word, they are able to fill in all the Sharepoint columns except for the lookup column.  When users click on the Show Details button, instead of showing a pop up allowing the user to fill in the metadata columns, nothing happens. This only happens with new documents.  If the user was to edit an existing document, the Show Details button works.

Thanks.

Comment: have you found any solution to this? I am currently in the same boat. I even tried creating new list/site content type/column from UI to rule out any errors that could happen if I deploy them via a solution. but I can't get that dialog to show up. MS talked about that the document information panel is deprecated and that we should click the show details button but it's not working! argh!